# missing lines because <br> in xml

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

i have a xml like this:

```
<cont><?php echo nl2br($cont); ?></cont>
```

the response is:

```
<cont>
2<br/>
3<br/>
4<br/>
</cont>
```

in the page the code is:

```
mainParentElement = document.getElementById('div_cont');
RemoveAllChildElements(mainParentElement);
mainParentElement.innerHTML = "<div class=\'div_cont\'>" + xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('cont')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +  "</div>";
```

in this case the result in the div is only the first line. (2)
if i deleted the `nl2br` the result is all the lines. (of course with out the `<br>`)

how can i add the `<br>`?

thank you!

Comment: what do you need to do with the return value of xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('cont')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue? is the XML doc for display as HTML or for datamanipulation?. If it's the first you shouldn't need to interate it, if it's the latter you don't need the br tags. (and no both is not an option, but it it can be a matter of timeing keeping them seperate)

Comment: i edited the question with the code from the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp).

There are characters that are not allowed as content of XML tags, like `<`, because for the parser they mark the beginning of a tag (obviously).
So if you want to have such data as content of a tag, you have to *escape* it somehow. In XML this is done by wrapping the content into `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`, which explicitly tells the parser to not interpret the data contained (treat it as **C** haracter **DATA**).

Basically you have to do:

```
<cont><![CDATA[<?php echo nl2br($cont); ?>]]></cont>
```

Comment: thank you! in IE it's working but in FF not. any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

adding `<br/>` will create new xml nodes. your content is then divided into :

```
2 (text node)
<br/> (xml node)
3 (text node)
<br/> (xml node)
4 (text node)
<br/> (xml node)
```

(xml node for the lack of a better word)

why do you need to add those linebreaks? if it's for presentation, i suggest adding them just before presenting them

Comment: it is for presentation. can you pls explain to me how to add the breaks? ( i edited the question with the relevant code)